# Using action as a key in a query string

Tags: craft2, querystring

I've been tasked with recreating an API within our Craft 2.X installation. For whatever reason, the API specifies the resource it is requesting with the query string parameter `action`. For example, instead of `baseurl.com/api/users`, they have it set up as `baseurl.com/api?action=users`

I thought I'd be okay if I used the ElementAPI plugin, set up an endpoint, and parsed the query string to figure out which set of elements to return as JSON. But it turns out that `action` is a very special query string parameter to Craft. When it receives a request containing `action`, Craft goes looking for a controller that will match it. I believe that Craft uses this pattern to handle a lot of basic business logic for the CMS. This seems like a very difficult branch of code to subvert -- this check fires before just about everything else.

Things I've tried, without luck:

- Changing the action trigger in the config file, in hopes of removing the magic from "action".
- Setting up a route in routes.php that goes directly to a plugin. Didn't work because UrlManager only fires after processActionRequest, which is the source of the error.
- Asking the people who maintain the API to change the endpoints they're looking for.

Assuming that I'm required to use "action" as a key in my query string, how can I accomplish that in Craft 2?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going to have to go up the chain to where the request starts - i.e. the server config. Rewrite all urls matching `api?action=...` to somewhere else. If you're using nginx it'd be something like

```
rewrite /api/$arg_action last;
```